# Virtual Host for SSL does not point to the specified folder

Tags: ssl, apache-2.4, virtualhost

I am using

```
Ubuntu 14.04
Apache Apache/2.4.7
```

I created a SSL Virtual host and provided the required key and cert files but the location it refers to is `/var/www/` instead of the provided folder location. Below is the virtual host file that I am using:

```
<VirtualHost 127.0.0.1:443>
    DocumentRoot /var/www/myfolder/myroot/
    ServerName www.mydomain.com:443
    ServerAlias www.mydomain.com:443
    ErrorLog logs/mydomain.com/error_ssl.log
    TransferLog logs/mydomain.com/access_ssl.log
    SSLEngine on
    SSLCertificateFile /etc/apache2/ssl/server.crt
    SSLCertificateKeyFile /etc/apache2/ssl/server.key
    <Directory /var/www/myfolder/myroot/>
        Options All
        AllowOverride All
        order allow,deny
        Allow from all
    </Directory>
    <FilesMatch "\.(cgi|shtml|phtml|php)$">
        SSLOptions +StdEnvVars
    </FilesMatch>
    <Directory /usr/lib/cgi-bin>
        SSLOptions +StdEnvVars
    </Directory>
    BrowserMatch ".*MSIE.*" \
        nokeepalive ssl-unclean-shutdown \
        downgrade-1.0 force-response-1.0
    </VirtualHost>
```

I tried the solutions provided [here](https://serverfault.com/questions/625204/virtual-host-not-pointing-to-folder).
As well tried using the below mentioned tag for virtual host:

```
<VirtualHost localhost:443>
<VirtualHost mydomain.com:443>
<VirtualHost 192.168.10.1:443> \\ my local IP on network
```

Post that also enabled the site `a2ensite mydomain.com`

Please suggest

Comment: Did you try with "www.mydomain.com" which is your ServerName (with "www") ? Is there an other host defined prior than this ?

Comment: This vhost has been defined in a separate file named 'www.mydomain.com'. Also, a relevant entry is available in sites-enabled. Also, this is the only vhost that is listening to 443.

Answer (score 0):

change opening virtual host tag from:

```
<VirtualHost 127.0.0.1:443>
```

to:

```
<VirtualHost _default_:443>
```

Justo to clarify: a virtual host is accessed when the tuple address/port in the VirtualHost declaration is matched.

The former tuple was matched only when the site was called from the server itself (127.0.0.1).

The `_default_` keyword matches any name accessed: a lot more appropriate for a default_ssl vhost.

That's why the virtual host's DocumentRoot was not honoured: the virtual host was not matched.

Comment: Changing that to _default also does not solve the purpose. It still points to '/var/www/'.

Comment: I agree with @Dom: you have another virtual host shadowing the one shown. You can make sure checking if the custom logfiles `logs/mydomain.com/access_ssl.log` gets populated when you access the site. I think they don't: it's a hint you are not accessing the expected vhost.

Comment: This answer would be better if it explained the difference between using `127.0.0.1` and `_default_` as well as what the change does to solve the problem.

Comment: Yes, the `logs/mydomain.com/access_ssl.log` are not being generated. Also, changing that to `_default_` does not work. Also, I have been creating vhost for long but this time I am stuck and could not find any error in the logs to rectify where I am not going fine.

Comment: @AnandSBahuguna It means another virtual host is "shadowing" your intended one. Please grep your apache2 conf (`/etc/apache2`) directory for the `SSLCertificateKeyFile`. This will point you to the offending vhost.

Comment: Did not find a single entry of `SSLCertificateKeyFile` in the file `/etc/apache2/apache2.conf`. Under `/etc/apache2/sites-available` the vhost file is named as `mydomain.com-ssl.conf`. Also Under the `/etc/apache2/sites-enabled` the link points to `../sites-available/mydomain.com-ssl.conf`